# JavaScript window resize with proportions

Tags: javascript, events, resize, popup, window

I open a window with `w=window.open('','', 'width=1000,height=700');` than i want this window to be resized with proportion 10/7.
for example: 500/350; 100/70 ...

i've maximum and minimum sizes already:

```
    var w;
function openwindow()
{
    w=window.open('','', 'width=1000,height=700');
    w.focus();

    resize(w);
}

function resize(w_obj) {


        w_obj.onresize = function(event) {
            width = w_obj.innerWidth;
            height = w_obj.innerHeight;

            // if popup width is greather then 1000px
            if (width > 1000) {
                w_obj.resizeTo(1000,700);
            }

            // if popup height is greather then 700px
            if(height >700) {
                w_obj.resizeTo(1000,700);
            }


            if (width < 500) {
                w_obj.resizeTo(500,350);
            }


            if(height < 350) {
                w_obj.resizeTo(500,350);
            }

        }


}
```

Comment: `w_obj.resizeTo(width, width*7/10);` ?

Comment: @David i've inserted your code in w_obj.onresize function and it caused infinite loop with window resize :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `outerHeight` as that's what `resizeTo`'s arguments mean. A problem however is that you cannot know whether the user resizes the width or the height of the window. Thus, you do not know what dimension to use as the reference and which to calculate.

Anyway, what you want is the following:

- Clamp `width` and `height` between its minimum and maximum size. You can use `Math.min`/`Math.max` for this.
- Set height to `width` multiplied by the `7 / 10` ratio.

See http://jsfiddle.net/bSE9C/1/.

```
var width = w_obj.outerWidth;
var height = w_obj.outerHeight;

width = Math.min(width, 1000);  // may not exceed 1000 maximum
height = Math.min(height, 700);

width = Math.max(width, 500);   // may not exceed 500 minimum
height = Math.max(height, 350);

height = width * 7 / 10;

w_obj.resizeTo(width, height);
```

Comment: onresize event can not run on opera

Comment: @Giorgi Komisia Berikelashvili: If the browser does not permit what you want then you're out of luck I'm afraid.